# Incomplete orthonormal systems in non separable Eulcidean spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

What I need is an example of an Euiclidean space (a vector space with a dot product) that is not separable and that does not have an orthonormal base.

I have been struggling with this exercise for a couple of days now. I know that every Hilbert space (a separable, complete, infinite-dimensional Euclidean space) always has a orthonormal basis that is countable. I am aware that not requiring the separability of the space allows the maximal set of orthogonal elements to be uncountable.

I also suspect that this space's Hamel Base has to be uncountably big. Otherwise we could use the Gran-Schmidt process to make the countable (Hamel) base orthonormal.

By not having an orthonormal basis I understand that the set of all finite linear combinations of any set of elements that are orthogonal to each other and of length 1 does not span the space (is this correct?).

Finally, what I think I need is to construct this example and then show that the cardinality of the Hamel Basis is greater than that of the maximal set of orthonormal elements. Or if it is easier, come up with an element of the space that can not be represented by a finite linear combination of elements of the (possibly uncountable) maximal set of orthonormal elements in the space.

Comment: Just a word of caution about terminology: what you refer to as a "dot product" is commonly known as an inner product, and I'm used to "Euclidean space" referring to specifically a finite-dimensional inner product space.

Comment: Oh, also "Hilbert Space" doesn't entail separability or infinite-dimensionality. It's just a complete inner product space.

Comment: How do you define "orthonormal basis"?

Comment: @TheoBendit That is the definition I've got in "Introductory Real Analysis" of Kolmogorov and Fomim, pg. 155.

Comment: @MartinArgerami And by orthonormal basis I mean a set of orthonormal elements such that the smallest closed subspace containing this set is the Euclidean space itself.

Comment: @MathiasBarreto Ah, weird. It's quite an old textbook. Maybe the words have slightly changed meanings since then.